# Simple jQuery Slideshow with fadein/fadeout

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadein

I have this really simple jQuery Slideshow: http://jsfiddle.net/6zA4B/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fadein">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
​$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});​
```

---

It works perfectly, I just want to replace the 3 img tags with 3 divs (so I can include a caption below the images). How can I modify the script to achieve that? I tried with this but probably I'm doing something wrong...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fadein">
    <p><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">image1</p>
    <p><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">image2</p>
    <p><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">image3</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('p').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/1/ :D

Comment: Please include the code *in* the question.

Comment: try out http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of your selectors is slightly off:

```
$('.fadein :first-child')
```

Is selecting all elements that are first children underneath `.fadein`. This includes the first child of the `p` elements, which are the images you're trying to rotate to.

You want to restrict the `:first-child` selector to elements directly under `.fadein`. One way would be to use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('.fadein > :first-child')
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/4/

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
    <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg"><p>image1</p></div>
<div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg"><p>image2</p></div>
    <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg"><p>image3</p></div>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
.fadein { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; }
.fadein div {position:absolute;text-align:center;height:100%;}
.fadein p { position:absolute; bottom:0;width:100%;color:white;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);height:1em;padding-bottom:10px;}​
```

JS:

```
$.fn.nextOrFirst = function(selector) {
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
}

$(function() {
    $('.fadein div:eq(0)').addClass("active");
    $('.fadein div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.active:eq(0)').fadeOut().removeClass("active").nextOrFirst('div').addClass("active").fadeIn().end()
    }, 3000);
});​
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/5/

Comment: I ahd to choose and I set Andrew as the correct answer because he explained my fault.. Thank you too, your solution works like a charm! ;))

Answer (score 0):

I like Andrew Whittaker's answer, but prefer to use the Fadeout callback to give it a little more "animation":

```
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein > :first-child').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).next('p').fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.fadein');   
})
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a plugin [jquery-fade-slider](http://jqueryfadeslider.com)

```
$(selector).fadeSlider()
```

[Link to Github Repo](https://github.com/jqueryfadeslider/jqueryfadeslider)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>add demo</title>
  <style>
    .slider{
       position: relative;
       width: 1000px;
       height: 300px;
       margin: 0px auto;
    }

    img {
       position: absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       width: 1000px;
       height: 300px;
    }
</style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
 
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){
    fade();
    setInterval(fade, 5000);
});
var i = 1;
function fade() {
  $('#img-' + i).fadeOut(2000);
  i++;
  if (i>3){
        i = 1
      }
    
  $('#img-' + i).fadeIn(2000);

}  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <img id="img-1" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1028/1921/1480.jpg?hmac=7rV8P9L5kV_5PMZcIIXOT-wN3gn7VwoYLl5YC4uNr0g">
        <img id="img-2" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/455/1922/1480.jpg?hmac=vqLUitWLN713y2jRmGcpEAChI9qUH5q7HB1yLjPNjYU">
        <img id="img-3" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/798/1920/1480.jpg?hmac=9yv1GtCO1YXMiM0ShMmoT-LJn0ZrV6A7a_aY0VWWqr8">
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```